# MySQL : How to automatically insert values on following FK columns?

Tags: mysql, database

[image: Sample Table (Edited)]
Suppose, I want to insert same values in 10 rows in FK columns(as per shown in image) automatically, say for e.g i have selected an Client named "JVL".  Now i want to insert its PK value (ClientID) multiple times to its FK column (Client_ClientID).  And then after few rows same thing for some other client. 
 How do i do this, please help.

Comment: The same way you can insert 1 row, you can insert multiple rows sequencially or stacked using `INSERT INTO table (column1, columnN) VALUES (value1, valueN), (value2, valueN), ...`

Comment: By "insert" do you mean "update"? Do you want to populate the client_id column of existing rows with random real client_id values?

Comment: @DanFromGermany: I didn't mean that, i want to make this happen automatically until the user changes Client , not manually by writing insert statement every time.

Comment: looking at the posted picture link; you need a `UPDATE` statement and not `INSERT`. Also, not sure how you will do this automatically? OR what you mean by `automatically`?

Comment: @Bohemian: I want to insert random ClientID values into an FK column(Client_ClientID). Checkout the mentioned link for image.

Comment: I have updated the image, apology for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a foreign key column of existing rows with valid random values:

```
update sometable set
client_clientid = (select clientid from client order by rand() limit 1)
```